# Calculating random effects from a glmerMod object (r package lme4)

Tags: random-variable, glmm, lme4-nlme

Using the `lme4` package, how does `ranef()` calculate (or extract) estimates of random effects from a `glmerMod` object? The random effects seem to be related to `model@u`, but what is the relationship?

On a related note, does anyone know of any sources that explain in detail what each of the components of a `glmerMod` object actually are? I can figure out some of them (e.g. `model@beta`), but most of them remain a mystery.

Comment: see `lme4:::ranef.merMod` and https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/AllClass.R to start?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see `ranef.merMod` takes the estimates of random effects from `model@pp$b(1)` and organizes them by factor groupings. Your [link](http://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/AllClass.R) was helpful, but most of it was over my head. I have much to learn...

Comment: [This](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/lMMwR/lrgprt.pdf) is also a very helpful source for understanding lme4 better.